# How much should doctrine record do?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, structure

I'm creating my own CMS and use doctrine for database.

Now I wonder, when I crate Post record, how much work should that record do?

An example:

I have Post -> Categories relation (one to many), should I create separate functions to append categories (to look if Post already has category, etc. ) or should Post do that using accessors / mutators?

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think adding methods for the purprose you described is a good idea. Doctrine can sometimes be a bit tricky if you try to override the default actions that happen when accessing the properties.

In general, if there's anything that needs more than the default action, I would recommend having it as a method in the model class.

If you have a specific table with some table-specific actions, such as get every object by some rule, then it's a good idea to add a new method to the table-specific SomeTable class.

Since this is kind of like ActiveRecord, you would have the domain logic in the Doctrine record object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will think more that way.